# Update a list using the filter in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular

I want to update list data using angular's filter option.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-category',
      templateUrl: './category.component.html'
    })
    export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {

      records: Array<any>;
      isDesc: boolean = false;
      column: string = 'CategoryName';
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.records= [
          { CategoryID: 1,  CategoryName: "Beverages", Description: "Coffees, teas" },
          { CategoryID: 2,  CategoryName: "Condiments", Description: "Sweet and savory sauces" },
          { CategoryID: 3,  CategoryName: "Confections", Description: "Desserts and candies" },
          { CategoryID: 4,  CategoryName: "Cheeses",  Description: "Smetana, Quark and Cheddar Cheese" },
          { CategoryID: 5,  CategoryName: "Grains/Cereals", Description: "Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal" },
          { CategoryID: 6,  CategoryName: "Beverages", Description: "Beers, and ales" },
          { CategoryID: 7,  CategoryName: "Condiments", Description: "Selishes, spreads, and seasonings" },
          { CategoryID: 8,  CategoryName: "Confections", Description: "Sweet breads" },
          { CategoryID: 9,  CategoryName: "Cheeses",  Description: "Cheese Burger" },
          { CategoryID: 10, CategoryName: "Grains/Cereals", Description: "Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal" }
         ];
         // here i want to update my list
          this.records.filter(u=>if(u.CategoryName=='Confections'){u.Description = 'Some description'}); // here the filter is throwing compile time exception
      }
    }
```

I am trying to update the list content using angular filter option but getting the compile time exception, please help resolve the issue.

Comment: This is not how to use filter. The method inside filter should return a `boolean` value and filter return a new array with all the elements  which return `true` after function execution. So in your case you should use a simple `this.records.forEach(u=>if(u.CategoryName=='Confections'){u.Description = 'Some description'});`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use `Array.filter`. [From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

It looks like you are simply trying to update a property of the items that match a predicate.

Instead you could just use a simple loop:

```
for (let u of this.records) {
  if(u.CategoryName == 'Confections') {
    u.Description = 'Some description'
  }
}
```

The reason you are getting a compile error is because `Array.filter()` expects a boolean returning function that it applies to every item in the array, e.g.

```
this.records.filter(x => x.prop === 'abc')
```

or

```
this.records.filter(x => {
  return x.prop === 'abc';
});
```